# Making a web extension app, how to include npm?

Tags: node.js, npm

I am currently working on making a web extension application(chrome app) and I want to use npm in my application. When I want to use npm on my computer, I had to simply download and install it on my computer. But if I want to put it into my application, I am not sure how to include this.
Like bootstrap, do I need to include a min.js file such as bootstrap.min.js?

(what I want to do with npm is to make a crawling to happen using cheeriojs!)

Is there anyone who knows how to include npm in this case?
Thanks in advance!! Any advice would be much appreciated! :)

Comment: `min` files are just minified files, not exactly npm files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`npm` is a package management tool. It has no place being *in* a Chrome extension.

If you want to use packages from NPM in a browser extension, then you'll typically want to use a tool like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) to transpile them from module format into a single ES5 file.

Note, however, that cheeriojs is:

> Fast, flexible & lean implementation of core jQuery designed specifically for the server.

… and since you want to run this in a browser, you should probably just use jQuery!

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted. Answer contains valid and useful information and explains why the question doesn't even make sense.